# python: return the exact match from list of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, exact-match

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
dictionary = {'happen1':['happen later'], 'happen2':['happen'], 'happen3':['happen later',' happen tomorrow'], 'happen4':['happen now'], 'happen5':['happen again','never happen']}
```

I have a string as follows.

```
my_string = 'happen this news on TV'
```

but I would like to do is to find the exact match of the first word of the string with the values in the dictionary and then replace it with the corresponding key.

```
def replacer():
    result = []
    for key,val in dictionary.items():
        if any(my_string.split(' ', 1)[0] in s for s in val):
            done= my_string.split(' ', 1)[0].replace(val, key.split(' ', 1)[0]) + ' to me' + ' ' + ' '.join(my_string.split()[1:])
            result.append(done)
    return result
```

the current output:

```
['happen to me this news on TV', 'happen2 to me this news on TV', 'happen to me this news on TV', 'happen to me this news on TV', 'happen to me this news on TV']
```

the problem is when I run the function, it returns all possible matches, however I only want it to return the match for the value of the key 'happen2'. so the desired output would be:

```
['happen2 to me this news on TV']
```

Comment: `in s for s in val)`: I don't think you need the for loop: `val` is your list of strings, and the "first_word" `in val` would already try and match on (exact) strings inside that list. `if my_string.split(None, 1)[0] in val:` should be good enough (use `None` in case of e.g. a double space. Or go full regex and use word boundaries for the split. Also, do the split *before* the loop, so you do it once, not every loop iteration).

Comment: oh thank you very much, that actually solved the issue

Comment: That's what I figured. You were checking if a string was in a string, and "happen" will always be in any of your example strings. For a string to be in a list of strings, however, there needs to be an exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def replacer():
    my_words = my_string.split(" ")
    result = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        for item in value:
            if item == my_words[0]:
                result.append(key + " to me " + " ".join(my_words[1:]))
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it this way:-

```
def replacer(ms, md):
    tokens = ms.split()
    firstWord = tokens[0]
    for k, v in md.items():
        if firstWord in v:
            return k + ' ' + ' '.join(tokens[1:])

myString = 'happen this news on TV'
myDict = {'happen1':['happen later'], 'happen2':['happen'], 'happen3':['happen later',' happen tomorrow'], 'happen4':['happen now'], 'happen5':['happen again','never happen']}

print(replacer(myString, myDict))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def replacer(dictionary, string):
    replaced = []
    for key, val in dictionary.items():
        for v in val:
            if string.startswith(v):
                replaced.append(string.replace(v, key))
    return replaced
```

Output:

```
>>> dictionary = {'happen1':['happen later'], 'happen2':['happen'], 'happen3':['happen later',' happen tomorrow'], 'happen4':['happen now'], 'happen5':['happen again','never happen']}
>>> my_string = 'happen this news on TV'
>>> replacer(dictionary, my_string)
['happen2 this news on TV']
```